# How do I make the area brighter so I can see vertices in really dark areas or angles?

Tags: camera, vertices, lighting

I'm working on a model in blender and in certain angles, there's shadows that cover vertices and edges, making it really hard to see what I'm doing unless I go in at a really awkward angle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since you mentioned vertices, then I'm assuming you're talking about the viewport solid shading, right? Why don't you just use matcap shader, or change the color of the background from user preferences?

Comment: @Georges This happens regardless of what view I have, with material, textures or solids, so that's why I parented the second lamp to the camera (I'm self taught, so there's a lot of basic terms or tricks that I'm not familiar with yet) but thank you for the awesome tip :)

Comment: Nice trick, but is there a way to attach images or link .blend file so I (and other people) can understand the situation better? Also when it comes to Blender, who isn't self taught :)

Comment: @Georges I just updated the main question with a 2 part screenshot tutorial :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a really handy trick for this and maybe it will help someone else out too.

First, make a duplicate of your lamp.
Then position that second lamp so it's Behind your camera, not in front (really important)
Parent the lamp to the camera by dragging and dropping the lamp onto the camera in the hierarchy.
Finally, press 0 on your keypad to go into camera mode, then press Ctrl + F to go into free camera mode and move about normally.

You'll notice now that you have much more light then before and if you have multiple viewport windows open, you can even see the camera and lamp move around together (so you can see it working, not that useful but still cool!)

When you finished all your work on your model, delete the lamp :)

Hope this helps somebody out there! :)